# Why is Flexbox not vertically centering?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Trying to get a video frame to vertically and horizontally align in the browser. Here's what I have...

```css
body {
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}

#frame {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.video {
  width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div id="frame">
  <div class="video">
    <iframe  width="1200" height="675" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/dQw4w9WgXcQ?ecver=1" frameborder="0"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

The video centres horizontally, but not vertically.

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: I'm using Safari

Comment: In the example which you posted the flex element *is* actually vertically centered in it's parent's container. In order to see the effect of something being vertically centered - it's height must be less than the height of it's parant's container ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The element `#frame` gets the same height like the content (`.video`):

```css
body {
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}
#frame {
  border:1px dotted red;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}
.video {
  border:1px dotted blue;
  line-height:0;
  width:80%;
}
```

```html
<div id="frame">
  <div class="video">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/100x75"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

So the `.video` is centered vertically but you can't see it! If you add a height to the `#frame` larger than the content (`.video`), you can see the `.video` is centered vertically too! See the following example:

```css
body {
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}
#frame {
  border:1px dotted red;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height:200px;
}
.video {
  border:1px dotted blue;
  line-height:0;
  width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div id="frame">
  <div class="video">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/100x75"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nailed it. Thanks. I thought it would take the height from he body, but `#flex` is the parent

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

Remove `width` from `.video` and add `flex:0 auto` and `align-self:center`

```css
body {
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}

#frame {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.video {
  flex:0 auto;
  /* width: 100%; */
  align-self:center;
}
```

```html
<div id="frame">
  <div class="video">
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/dQw4w9WgXcQ?ecver=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

add the below code

```
 padding-top:50%; in css
```

https://jsfiddle.net/anandnaha/km83v9rv/

Answer (score 0):

Hardcoding width and height in iframe is not a good practice.

I hope this works for you.

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.video {
  width: 80%;
}

iframe {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<div id="frame">
  <div class="video">
    <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/dQw4w9WgXcQ?ecver=1" frameborder="0"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```